# Firebase Function: How to call regional function based on client's location

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions, geolocation

**Setup**

I have deployed Firebase functions worldwide as follows:

```js
// index.ts

const regionArr = ["europe-west3", "us-central1", "asia-south1"];

exports.superDuperFunction = 
  functions.region(...regionArr).https.onCall(async (data, context) => { ... }
```

And I am calling the function(s) as follows:

```dart
// flutter.dart

HttpsCallableResult response =
  await FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: "europe-west3")
    .httpsCallable('createCheckoutSession')
    .call(<String, dynamic>{ ... }
```

**The Plan (tm)**

I would like to deploy the App with the same code base to multiple regions. I would like to avoid hard-coding the Firebase function's location and tinkering with the App's source for each deploy.

**Question**

How can the App detect its region and call the closest function dynamically : `["europe-west3", "us-central1", "asia-south1"]` ?

If in Asia, call `asia-south1`, if in Europe call `europe-west3` ?

**Possible Solution**

One option could be to map the device's `locale` to the most suiting location. But this would require mapping all possible `locale`'s to the locations Google offers for its cloud functions manually.

There has to be a better, more generic solution.

Answer (score 1):

A [HTTPS load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless#set_up_regional_routing) would be the straightforward solution. 
Alternatively, if you have a few regions far apart, you can use timezone or location information as you've mentioned in your question. I had posted a similar code snippet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75112435/13130697).